# Bottom Up Recursive SUM (lowest level only has values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a tree-based structure of SKUs within a Product Hierarchy in SQL Server. The lowest level SKUs will only ever have values (these are consumption values). I then want to generate aggregates up the hierarchy at every level.

Here's is the sample table structure:

| Id | ParentId | Name | Volume | IsSku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | All | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | Cat A | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Cat B | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | Cat A.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | Cat A.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | Cat B.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | Cat B.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 4 | SKU1 | 10 | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | SKU2 | 5 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | SKU3 | 7 | 1 |
| 11 | 5 | SKU4 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 6 | SKU1 | 10 | 1 |
| 13 | 6 | SKU2 | 5 | 1 |
| 14 | 7 | SKU3 | 9 | 1 |
| 15 | 7 | SKU4 | 7 | 1 |

I need a query that will start at the sku level (IsSku=1) and then working up, will sum the SKUs and carry the sum up the product category levels to get a cumulative running total.

I've seen several queries where there are recursive sums in a hierarchical structure where each level already has values, but I need one that will start at the lowest level that has values and recursively calculate the sum as it moves upward.

I was trying these, but they look like they are mainly summing hierarchical data where each node already has a value (Volume, in my case). I need to start at the lowest level and carry the aggregate up as I go up the hierarchy. I tried to emulate the answers in these posts with my data, but wasn't successful so far with my data setup.

- [24394601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure)
- [29127163](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127163/sql-server-bom-recursion-from-the-bottom-up)
- [11408878](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408878/recursive-sum-sql-server)

The output for the query should be like so:

| Id | ParentId | Name | Volume | IsSku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | All | 54 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | Cat A | 26 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Cat B | 28 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | Cat A.1 | 15 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | Cat A.2 | 11 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | Cat B.1 | 12 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | Cat B.2 | 16 | 0 |
| 8 | 4 | SKU1 | 10 | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | SKU2 | 5 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | SKU3 | 7 | 1 |
| 11 | 5 | SKU4 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 6 | SKU1 | 10 | 1 |
| 13 | 6 | SKU2 | 2 | 1 |
| 14 | 7 | SKU3 | 9 | 1 |
| 15 | 7 | SKU4 | 7 | 1 |

I've got a start with a recursive CTE that returns the hierarchy can can aggregate the volume if that node has volume already, but can't seem to figure out how to start at the SKU levels and continue aggregating up the hierarchy.

Here's the start with my CTE:

```
DECLARE @tblData TABLE
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] INT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Volume] int NOT NULL,
    [IsSku] bit
)

INSERT INTO @tblData
VALUES 
 (1,-1,'All',0,0)
,(2,1,'Cat A',0,0)  
,(3,1,'Cat B',0,0)  
,(4,2,'Cat A.1',0,0)  
,(5,2,'Cat A.2',0,0)  
,(6,3,'Cat B.1',0,0)  
,(7,3,'Cat B.2',0,0)  
,(8,4,'SKU1',10,1)  
,(9,4,'SKU2',5,1)  
,(10,5,'SKU3',7,1)  
,(11,5,'SKU4',4,1)  
,(12,6,'SKU1',10,1)  
,(13,6,'SKU2',5,1)  
,(14,7,'SKU3',7,1)  
,(15,7,'SKU4',4,1)  

;WITH cte AS (   
    SELECT
        a.ID
        ,a.ParentID
        ,a.Name
        ,a.Volume
        ,CAST('/' + cast(ID as varchar) + '/' as varchar) Node
        ,0 AS level
        ,IsSku
    FROM @tblData AS a
    WHERE a.ParentID = -1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        b.ID
        ,b.ParentID
        ,b.Name
        ,b.Volume
        ,CAST(c.Node + CAST(b.ID as varchar) + '/' as varchar)
        ,level = c.level + 1
        ,b.IsSku
    FROM @tblData AS b  
    INNER JOIN cte c
        ON b.ParentId = c.ID
)

SELECT c1.ID, c1.ParentID, c1.Name, c1.Node
    ,ISNULL(SUM(c2.Volume),0)
FROM cte c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.Node <> c2.Node
    AND LEFT(c2.Node, LEN(c1.Node)) = c1.Node
GROUP BY c1.ID, c1.ParentID, c1.Name, c1.Node
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the query you have so far?

Comment: I don;t quite understand the expected results: eg `ID=15` has `Volume=4` in the sample, but `Volume=7` in the output?

Comment: @Charlieface, my bad. I fixed the source values.

Comment: @Stu, I updated with my original starting data, cte and query.

Comment: @DaleK, thanks for the feedback. I added some other posts I had looked at to try and emulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT, ParentId INT, Name NVARCHAR(255), Volume INTEGER, IsSku BIT)
 
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES 
 (1,-1,'All',0,0)
,(2,1,'Cat A',0,0)  
,(3,1,'Cat B',0,0)  
,(4,2,'Cat A.1',0,0)  
,(5,2,'Cat A.2',0,0)  
,(6,3,'Cat B.1',0,0)  
,(7,3,'Cat B.2',0,0)  
,(8,4,'SKU1',10,1)  
,(9,4,'SKU2',5,1)  
,(10,5,'SKU3',7,1)  
,(11,5,'SKU4',4,1)  
,(12,6,'SKU1',10,1)  
,(13,6,'SKU2',5,1)  
,(14,7,'SKU3',7,1)  
,(15,7,'SKU4',4,1)  
SELECT * FROM @tbl
;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT       
        Id,ParentId, Name, Volume, IsSku, CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Hierarchy
    FROM       
        @tbl
    WHERE ParentId=-1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        t.Id,t.ParentId, t.Name, t.Volume, t.IsSku, CAST(c.Hierarchy + '|' + CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM 
        cte c 
        INNER JOIN @tbl t
            ON c.Id = t.ParentId

)
SELECT Id,ParentId, Name, ChildVolume AS Volume, IsSku
FROM (
    SELECT c1.Id, c1.ParentId, c1.Name, c1. Volume, c1.IsSku, SUM(c2.Volume) AS ChildVolume
    FROM cte c1
        LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.Hierarchy LIKE c1.Hierarchy + '%'
    GROUP BY c1.Id, c1.ParentId, c1.Name, c1. Volume, c1.IsSku
) x
```

Basically the computation happens in three steps:

1. Capture the Hierarchy recursively for each descendant by concatenating the Ids: `CAST(c.Hierarchy + '|' + CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))`
2. Join the resulting table with itself so each record is joined with itself and all its descendants: `FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.Hierarchy LIKE c1.Hierarchy + '%'`
3. Finally aggregate the Volume of each hierarchy by grouping: `SUM(c2.Volume) AS ChildVolume`

This is in reference to Ed Harper's answer to a similar question here: [Hierarchy based aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430980/hierarchy-based-aggregation)

Comment: Excellent! I had the cte right and was capturing the hierarchy into a column in a simlar way, but was trying to figure out the next piece that you have in the final query. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to be careful about matching ids with multiple digits.  For example if 11 and 1 are both root nodes, then 11 will mistakenly be matched by `LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.Hierarchy LIKE c1.Hierarchy + '%'`.  I think putting the `|` after the id instead of before it will fix these false matches.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way that recursive CTEs work in SQL Server, it is very difficult to get this kind of logic working efficiently. It often either requires self-joining the whole resultset, or using something like JSON or XML.

The problem is that at each recursion of the CTE, although it *appears* you are working on the whole set at once, it actually only feeds back one row at a time. Therefore grouping is disallowed over the recursion.

**Instead, it's much better to simply recurse with a `WHILE` loop** and insert into a temp table or table variable, then read it back to aggregate

> Use the `OUTPUT` clauses to view the intermediate results

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
  Id INTEGER,
  ParentId INTEGER,
  Name VARCHAR(7),
  Volume INTEGER,
  IsSku INTEGER,
  Level INT,
  INDEX ix CLUSTERED (Level, ParentId, Id)
);

INSERT INTO @tmp
  (Id, ParentId, Name, Volume, IsSku, Level)
-- OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.ParentId, inserted.Name, inserted.Volume, inserted.IsSku, inserted.Level
SELECT
  p.Id,
  p.ParentId,
  p.Name,
  p.Volume,
  p.IsSku,
  1
FROM Product p
WHERE p.IsSku = 1;

DECLARE @level int = 1;
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmp
      (Id, ParentId, Name, Volume, IsSku, Level)
    -- OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.ParentId, inserted.Name, inserted.Volume, inserted.IsSku, inserted.Level
    SELECT
      p.Id,
      p.ParentId,
      p.Name,
      t.Volume,
      p.IsSku,
      @level + 1
    FROM (
        SELECT
          t.ParentID,
          Volume = SUM(t.Volume)
        FROM @tmp t
        WHERE t.Level = @level
        GROUP BY
          t.ParentID
    ) t
    JOIN Product p ON p.Id = t.ParentID;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
        
    SET @level += 1;
END;

SELECT *
FROM @tmp
ORDER BY Id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=228ada060f56bca484795f680ceeb86a)

This solution does involve a blocking operator, due to Halloween protection (in my case I saw an "unnecessary" sort). You can avoid it by using [Itzik Ben-Gan's *Divide and Conquer* method](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/divide-and-conquer-halloween), utilizing two table variables and flip-flopping between them.

Comment: "Instead, it's much better to simply recurse with a WHILE loop" - I never thought I'd hear you say these words :)

Comment: Yeah, well SQL Server doesn't do recursion well. See also this excellent article by Dwain Camps going into the performance characteristics https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/the-performance-of-traversing-a-sql-hierarchy/

Comment: Oh, I fully understand its the best tool for the job in some circumstances :) just quite funny given how often we are commenting "use set-based operations" lol

Comment: Oddly enough, rCTE's are actually *less* set-based than this, because it works one row at a time. Note how I'm inserting a full level at a time, and that the table variable is properly indexed. An rCTE also uses a table variable internally, just less efficiently.

Comment: I think a lot of people confuse the conciseness of a query with its performance. A CTE looks pretty but in my experience frequently performs badly.

Comment: Ironically, I had started with a while loop that got the MIN(ID) where IsSku = 1 into a variable and then got the next based on ID > variable and then walking up the hierarchy, but it seemed slow. I need to try this approach as well and compare perf.

Comment: That will be because you were processing one row at a time, whereas this processes a whole level at a time. It won't actually loop that many times in real-life scenarios